# Sum of absolute differences and Manhattan distance for image analysis

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-figure

I wish to find out close resemblance of *'A' with 'B'* image and *'A' with 'C'* image.
The result sum of absolute difference of *'A'and 'B' or 'A'and 'C'*  which gives less that will be treated as close to *'A'* *among 'B' and 'C'*.

I have used following matlab code for this purpose.

```
sad_natural=imabsdiff(InputImage,ReconstructedImage_natural);
sad_knn=imabsdiff(InputImage,ReconstructedImage_KNN);

figure('Name','sad_natural','NumberTitle','off'),imshow(sad_natural,[]);
figure('Name','sad_knn','NumberTitle','off'),imshow(sad_knn,[]);
```

Here it give me two images. But i want to find out distance between them(close-ness). How can i use  Manhattan distance in matlab.

Comment: Your question is (at least to me) a bit vague. What have you done with `ReconstructedImage_natural` and `ReconstructedImage_KNN`? And what do you mean with "you get two images"? That's kind of obvious when you use `imabsdiff` twice. Also you should explain what you want to do with the manhattan-distance as if someone has never heard of "Similarity of two images".

Answer (score 0):

As you noted yourself, [`imabsdiff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imabsdiff.html) returns an *image* with the per-pixel absolute differences. If you want a single number that represents the the "distance between two images", you may want to look at

```
 myDistA_B = mean( sad_natural(:) );
 myDistA_C = mean( sad_knn(:) );
```

and based on these numbers you can decide if `B` is a better reconstruction of A than `C` or vice versa.

Comment: This is what i am expecting. mean(x(:)).